# How to remove data type from http get service

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I have created http get service that is returning collection data as json. But I don't want to show column data type

This is my function code.

```
const result =  doc.find({},{id:1,desc:1,label:1,LocationTree:1,path:1,coordinates:1,_id: 0}).toArray();
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I contacted MongoDB support about this issue when I first started with Stitch. They indicated there is no way to suppress the type returned with *numeric* and *datetime* value types.

Your client application must **handle the type when processing the JSON response**. This is done with dot notation.

Assume your `id` field is of type `Int32`.

A typical API call might return an integer or string at `result.id`. The Stitch HTTP service, however, appends the type to the value, returning it at `result.id.$numberInt`.

As noted above, type data is included with *numeric* and *datetime* values. Booleans, Strings, Objects, and Arrays do not include type data. They can be accessed at `result.someBoolean`, `result.someString`, `result.someObject`, or `result.someArray`.

I haven't found a full list of types returned by the Stitch HTTP service. For some reason, they do NOT match the [BSON Type aliases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).

Comment: Thank you for this information. But mongdb stitch is like middle-ware in between client app and mongdb, so there should have a handler for keep or avoid this . Because if we are providing this api to any third party who already following a json standard,  they can't write code only our api. I mean, plug and play platforms